# Show that $\frac{\sin 2kx}{2\sin x}+\cos(2k+1)x=\frac {\sin[2(k+1)x]}{2\sin x}$

Tags: trigonometry

I have a proof question
Context: It was part of a homework question. I should have thought about product to sums.

Show that $\frac{\sin 2kx}{2\sin x}+\cos(2k+1)x=\frac {\sin[2(k+1)x]}{2\sin x}$

I tried many ways such as using double angle identity or compound angle identities and combining the LHS into one fraction but it never worked out. I am in a daze. Please help

Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Could you include some of the ‘many ways’ you tried? Or the community might come to believe this is just a homework question…

Comment: It *does* work with the double angle identities.

Comment: @soham saha it is a homework question as many questions on this site are. Should I put pictures of my 3+ pages of scribbles on the back of Mendelssohn trio sheet music as evidence that I tried?

Comment: Many questions of this site may be homework questions but that doesn’t mean that this community is just meant to be a group of homework solvers. We believe in bidirectional knowledge sharing. Posting some of your work would let people try to help you move towards the goal, instead of explicitly telling you how to solve a particular question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just needs rearrangement from here:

$$\sin(2(k+1)x)-\sin(2kx)=2\sin(x)\cos((2k+1)x)$$

**Hint:** Think about $\sin c-\sin d$ formula

Comment: Thank you. May I ask of what form an equation should be such that, when proving it, one requires this sinc-sind formula? Like, how do I recognise when to use it? although I do see how you came to directly to that formula.

Comment: The way I see it is that for any proof based question, you should try to work backwards. I just saw your problem and went back to find the simplest form that matched in my memory a previously seen form, the sinc-sind formula. Then I checked if everything worked and there you go.

Answer (score 2):

Applying the double-angle identities several times,

\begin{align}
\sin(2(k+1)x)=\sin(2kx+2x)\\
\\
=\sin (2kx) \cos (2x) + \cos (2kx) \sin (2x) = \sin (2kx)(1-2\sin^2 x) + 2\sin x \cos x \cos(2kx)\\
\\
= \sin (2kx) + 2( \cos(2kx) \cos x -  \sin(2kx)\sin x ) \sin x\\
\\
= \sin(2kx) + 2\cos(2kx + x)\sin x = \sin(2kx) + 2\cos((2k+1)x)\sin x. \\
\end{align}

This yields

$$ \sin(2(k+1)x) = \sin(2kx) + 2\cos((2k+1)x)\sin x.$$

Dividing both sides by $ 2\sin x $ gives the result.

Comment: There were some errors but I believe I have fixed them now.